# How to remove a range of elements of a vector ever changing its size (C++)?

Tags: c++, vector, range, erase

I have a rather interesting problem (interesting to me anyway, being a beginner and all): In C++ one can rather easily grow a vector with push_back(), which one can then simply put into a loop to grow as much as needed. The problem is, that I found no similar easy functionality for reducing its size. What I really want to do, is to have a vector with a predefined size,  and then let's say remove the second half of it entirely (not just the elements contained, but the vector size should also be reduced). An example:

```
vector<int> numrange;
for (int i=0; i<=100; ++i) {numrange.push_back(i);}
```

This works perfectly for growing the vector and filling it with a numbers. But this doesn't seem to be allowed:

```
int vectsize=numrange.size();
for (int i=vectsize; i>=(vectsize/2); --i) {numrange.erase(i);}
```

You see, I want to erase every element above 50, but it won't work. Something to do with "no known conversion from int to const iterator"

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looks like you might need the erase remove idiom

Comment: `numrange.resize(numrange.size()/2);` will resize `numsize` to contain only the first `numrange.size()/2` elements, destructing the latter half of the elements in the vector.

Comment: When you say "the vector size should also be reduced", do you mean "reduce the value returned by`size`", or do you mean "reduce the value returned by `size` and `capacity`"?  The latter is harder (it was almost impossible in C++98, I think there are mechanisms in more recent versions).

Comment: The mechanism is [`shrink_to_fit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit)

Comment: @Martin Bonner By "the vector size should also be reduced" I meant the value returned by numrange.size(); the capacity is not relevant at the moment.

Comment: @jaggedSpire Will this method enable me to remove the first half of elements if need be? I'd like to have a very adaptable method to remove elements, which ultimately would enable me to remove any range from anywhere within the original vector. Thanks

Comment: @pusrob nope, for that you'll want the `vector::erase` member function user2296177 mentions in their answer.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector<>`'s `erase()` member function takes an iterator of type `std::vector<>::const_iterator`. You are supplying an `int` to the function, thus the call cannot be made as an `int` does not implicitly convert to `std::vector<>::const_iterator`.

You need to offset an iterator in the following way:

```
numrange.erase(numrange.cbegin() + i);
```

However, please note that you initialize `i` to `vectsize`, which was itself initialized to `numrange.size()`. This means that you try to erase one element past the end of your range. You should use `numrange.size() - 1`.

Additionally, there are overloads that erase a range to which you can apply the same offset principle:

```
numrange.erase(numrange.cbegin() + numrange.size() / 2, numrange.cend());
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `erase` of `std::vector` expects an iterator instead of an `int` index as argument.

You can use the begin-iterator and just add the amount of elements to skip to reach the desired iterator:

```
for (int i=vectsize; i>=(vectsize/2); --i) {numrange.erase(numrange.begin()+i);}
```